# MapInfo WMS Authentication

Tags: wms, mapinfo, authentication

I am trying to setup a WMS service to pass basic authentication credentials within MapInfo (using a master username and password). The end result being a layer visible to the organisation where each person is not required to enter their authentication details.

I have setup the WMS service, and ensured my credentials work. I have researched and tried https://username:Password@remaining URl. But with no luck. I cannot seam to find something to assist me.

Usually my WMS services are free access, if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: In theory, MapInfo should automatically ask for user/password when actually connecting.

Comment: Yes, @CL you are correct. I would like to remove this request dialogue box from displaying so its seamless for the users. I dont know if this is possible though as i haven't come across a solution in my research.

Comment: Does your MI version (which one?) allow you to save the password?

Comment: I am using mapinfo 15.0.3. Yes, mapinfo remembers the password, which is great. However I cannot make the layer live with the dialogue box appearing as the users will not accept this.