# Embed WMS server login info into MapInfo tab file

Tags: wms, mapinfo, tab

I need to create a .tab file that opens a restricted/protected WMS server without prompting for credentials every time.

Currently when I open it, a prompt for the user name and password comes up. I don't want to give this to all the users on the system but have it embedded in the .tab/.xml file...ideally scrambled.

The .tab is

```
!table
!version 750
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
File "qld_sisp_imagery_wms.xml"
Type "WMS"
CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 116, "m", 147, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 10000000
begin_metadata
"\IsReadOnly" = "FALSE"
"\MapInfo" = ""
"\MapInfo\TableID" = "8b6009d6-c314-4bd4-9223-d7d290ed84e4"
end_metadata
```

the .xml is

```
<MI_WMS_MapDefinition version="1.0" wms_version="1.3.0"><HTTP GetCapabilities="https://auth-spatial-XXX/ImageServer/WMSServer?" GetMap="https://auth-spatial-XXX/ImageServer/WMSServer"/><Exception format="XML"/><SRS>EPSG:28355</SRS><Image bgcolor="16777215" transparent="true" format="image/png"/><Layer><Name>LatestStateProgram_SISPUsers</Name><Style></Style><LatLonBoundingBox minx="-180" miny="-90" maxx="180" maxy="90"/><BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:28355" minx="-481881.729993" miny="6734668.137079" maxx="1225547.023262" maxy="8981699.047294"/></Layer></MI_WMS_MapDefinition>
```

QGIS enables this in it's convert to configuration process when you add a WMS feed.

Is there a similar MI process?

Comment: Can't you add username/password (or appropriate parameter names and values) to the service URLs like `GetMap="https://auth-spatial-XXX/ImageServer/WMSServer?user=xxx&password=###&`

Comment: Or you can try to include Basic auth into the url as `https://username:password@server.com/...`

Comment: Duplicate of [MapInfo WMS Authentication](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/308465/10588), which has no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this and it's a requested feature in mapinfo - https://ideas.pitneybowes.com/ideas/MIPRO-I-1012

Please upvote this request to help get a resolution as soon as possible.